# Select from MultiIndex by labels with repetitions

Tags: pandas

I have difficulties to make selection from MultiIndex in `pandas 0.14.1` (*I know that is old version, but my choice is limited*).

**I need to do selection based on index labels.**

For one level index selection goes **fine with repetitions**

```
(pd.DataFrame
.from_records({'A' : [1,2,3], 'B' : [11,12,13]})
.set_index('A')
).loc[idx[1,1,1,2,1], :]

    B
A    
1  11
1  11
1  11
2  12
1  11
```

For multilevel index selection works in different way, **taking only unique values**.

```
(pd.DataFrame
.from_records({'A' : [1,2,3], 'B' : [11,12,13], 'C' : [21,22,23]})
.set_index(['A', 'B'])
).loc[idx[[1,1,1,2,1], :], :]

       C
A B     
1 11  21
2 12  22
```

**QUESTION: Is there anyway to use multiindex but preserve selection behaviour from single level index?** The expected output is like in single index, thus, 5 rows in return, not 2

Comment: This will never be possible, because it will raise into question, how to treat duplicates in the second level. For each value in level 1, return all? Or 1? How many should be returned? You're asking for the impossible, and quite frankly I'm glad they haven't implemented this.

Comment: @COLDSPEED for me it is clear that it should return all, given explicit selection of all with `:` in `idx[[1,1,1,2,1], :]`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Impossible you say (-; My favorite kind of problem.

Answer (score 2):

Best I could come up with.  Be warned, this will blow up for many reasons and I fully expect you to come back with "But this didn't work on my real data."

**Option 1**
This will always work, but may not always be what you expected.

```
pd.concat([df.xs(i, drop_level=False) for i in [1, 1, 1, 2, 1]])

       C
A B     
1 11  21
  11  21
  11  21
2 12  22
1 11  21
```

---

**Option 2**
This will break if your first level values aren't unique on their own.

```
df.iloc[df.index.get_level_values(0).searchsorted([1, 1, 1, 2, 1])]

       C
A B     
1 11  21
  11  21
  11  21
2 12  22
1 11  21
```